# Insert Into Oracle Table with single, autoincrement Column

Tags: sql, oracle, insert-into

#### Imagine the following (**fictional**) situation:

You have a table with only one column `id` that is the primary key, autoincremented by using a typical sequence + trigger combination.

---

How would you create a new row there as you have to specify the values keyword for the insert query?

`INSERT INTO table () VALUES ()` is not valid as far as I understood.

---

#### ATTENTION:

This is not a discussion about the sense of such a table! It is out of pure technical interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any current Oracle version (12.1, 12.2, 18) I would not use a trigger but an `identity` column - then use the `default` keyword during insert:

```
create table x (id integer generated by default as identity);
insert into x (id) values (default);
```

Comment: I think that you should stress that this is only possible in Oracle `12` and not in previous versions.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
INSERT INTO theTable (id) VALUES (null);
```

and  your **before insert** trigger would be like:

```
if  :NEW.id is NULL Then  
   SELECT id_sequence.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.id FROM dual; 
end if;
```